# How Do I Access The Panorama Control on my MainPage, From a ViewModel

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'll mention the specifics first, and then mention what I'm trying to do.

I have a method in my NewPersonViewModel

```
private void AddNewPerson()
{
     // code to get Panoroma
     // more code to get the active panorama item
    _navigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri(@"/View/NewPerson.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

But I'm not sure how to get the reference to my MainPage's Panorama.

I know how to get the property of another ViewModel, like this:

```
var mainvm = (new ViewModelLocator()).Main;
mainvm.Milestones.Add(NewMilestone);
```

However, unlike the Milestones property above, the Panorama is just a ui control in the mainpage.xaml and I don't have that available as something to retrieve from code.

I'm using MVVMlight.

I think they're shutting off internet access here in this building, gotta send.
Steve

Comment: What are you trying to get from the pano?

Comment: I just simply want the Panorama's selecteditem index.  That index, i.e, which 'page' the user is on,  will decide what parameter I will send in the "/View/NewPerson.xaml" url that I'm navigating to.

Comment: Should've added:  

That url should be: /View/NewPerson.xaml?type=pan_index

Answer (score 0):

In general, the point of MVVM is that your ViewModel does not directly talk to the View. If your View needs to display something, it will have a Data Binding to your ViewModel.

In regard to your code, the solution is to create a public property on your ViewModel that you set in the View's code-behind constructor, through the ViewModelLocator. That way, anyone with a reference to your ViewModel has a reference to that specific View.

---

PanoramaViewModel.cs

```
    ViewModel {
        public Panorama m_Panorama {get;set;}
        ...
    }
```

PanoramaView.xaml

```
    <phone:Panorama x:Name="AddPersonPanorama">
    ...
    </phone:Panorama>
```

PanoramaView.xaml.cs

```
    PanoramaView {
        PanoramaView() {
            App.ViewModelLocator.ViewModel.m_Panorama = this.AddPersonPanorama;
        }

    }
```

ReferenceToPanorama.cs

```
    Class {
        App.ViewModelLocator.ViewModel.m_Panorama.DoSomething();
    }
```

I would suggest reading up on MVVM and thinking of a more MVVM-way of achieving this. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, you're right about becoming more familiar with MVVM to follow that pattern more legitimately. I was going to post a question on Laurent's forum, but wanted to avoid posting too many questions that aren't specifically related to his framework(mvvmlight). Your suggestion is good, and gives me direction to go, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectedindex%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in your viewmodel, you should be able to bind directly to it.

In your xaml:

```
<phone:Panorama SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedPageIndex, Mode=OneWyToSource}">
    <!-- items -->
</phone:Panorama>
```

In your Viewmodel

```
private int _index;
public int SelectPageIndex
{
    get { return _index; }
    set { _index = value; }
    // no need for property changed event if only getting
}
```

Now when you need it from access the property

```
int currentPage = SelectedPageIndex;
string uri = string.Format("/View/NewPerson.xaml?type={0}", currentPage);
_navigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
```

If you cannot bind to it, you could subscribe to the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectionchanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event and set the SelectedPageIndex from that event handler

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
{
    ViewModel.SelectedPageIndex = CCPanorama.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: OMG, can it be this easy. Why didn't I think of simply binding that puppy? Thank you.

Comment: Weird, when I added that attribue to the Panorama XAML, I get:  
"Error  The property "SelectedIndex" does not have an accessible setter. "  I'll check the docs.

Comment: can you try setting the Mode to OneWayToSource

Comment: Getting the same actually. My code in the xaml is:

    <phone:Panorama Name="CCPanorama" Title="My Title" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedPageIndex, Mode=OneWayToSource}">

  And in my MainViewModel, which is the source for the page of course, is your code:

    private int _index;
    public int SelectPageIndex
    {
        get { return _index; }
        set { _index = value; }
       // no need for property changed event if only getting
    }

In the meantime, I'm using dBlisse's solution, but eventually will resolve this and get that code out of the mainpage.xaml.cs.

Comment: included a new answer

Comment: Thanks, I will try the selectionchanged handler.